# What is the best metric to measure the spread/skewness of a distribution about 0 rather than the mean?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have ordered bar charts and would like to use a metric to compare the shape of the distributions. Some bar charts are virtually flat, with all bars reaching the same y-values, whilst others have a very high standard deviation with the first bars reaching very high values and the last bars reaching very low values, and then other bar charts can fit anywhere between these two extremes, please see figures. [image: Flat distribution][image: steep distribution]

I don't think standard deviation is an ideal metric for these distributions, because it is possible to have a very high top value and a very low bottom value but have most of the middle values skewed towards the top value. I would have chosen skewness but is it possible to measure skewness about 0 rather than about the mean?

Comment: Variance and the square root of variance (i.e. standard deviation) are useful. You can also add [Skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) to capture the imbalance you're talking about and possibly [kurtosis or excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) to capture fat tails.

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a single measure I could use? I have lots of these graphs and ideally I would have a single metric to compare their shapes. I suppose the measure would be the gradient of the line of best fit across the top of the bars? But this doesn't seem very proper.

Comment: Calculating mean, variance (or standard deviation), and skewness would be a completely standard thing to do. If the specifics of your problem suggest a more useful statistic for comparison, you could use it, but the burden would then be on you to justify why you're doing what you're doing instead of just giving the standard summary statistics.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to measure skewness about zero instead of the mean? (I believe i could justify this)

Comment: E[x^3] is the 3rd [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) and would be a standard, understandable measure. Skewness is the 3rd standardized moment (i.e. 3rd moment but re-centered at the mean and scaled by standard deviation).

Answer (score 0):

From [this Matlab help file](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalized-pareto-distribution.html):

> Like the exponential distribution, the generalized Pareto distribution is often used to model the tails of another distribution.

You can fit a Pareto distribution using [`gpfit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/gpfit.html) that returns the tail (shape) and the scale parameters.

*Need to run the Statistics toolbox though.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is good, but looks like it can only be used for the second extreme i defined and couldn't be used for the flatter distributions